# Minimum number to divide a number into different parts

Tags: algorithm

Assume we have a number with n non-zero digits and a list B  of b index numbers. Each number in the list represents a place where the number is split. Suppose it takes n steps to split a number with n digits into two numbers.

For all numbers in B holds that 0 < b < n and all elements in B are unique. 
A number b indicates that the split should happen between Index b and b+1 ( The first digit of the number has an index of 1).

Example: 12345 and b = {1,2}

First order 1,2:

1) We get 1 and 2345 with 5 steps.

2) We get 1 and 2 and 345 with 4 steps.

So this order needs in total 9 steps.

Second order 2,1:

2) We get 12 and 345 with 5 steps.

1) We get 1 and 2 and 345 with 2 steps.

So this order needs in total 7 steps. So for this example, the minimum number of steps is 7 and the optimal order is 2,1.

I am looking for an algorithm that calculates the minimum number of steps and determines the optimal order. I have tried to solve this problem with dynamic programming, but can't really get any further.

Comment: Even if you haven't been able to get very far, you should include your work so far for a more complete question.

Comment: @juvian Thanks, I missed that phrase

Comment: How many digits and how big is B?

Comment: @juvian There should be no limitation in the algorithm.

Comment: @MBo heh, linked your own answer for same problem

Comment: @juvian :)) I knew this is kind of "cutting rod" but forgot about that theme.